# Other colors in Ncurses?

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

I'm playing with ncurses and i'm trying to draw Mario on the screen, but I can't get some colors. I don't know if this is really possible but I would like to create new colors like COLOR_SKIN and set a RGB code to it.

If I can't do this with ncurses, is there another way to do this?

This is the image:

[image: hi im mario]

Comment: Check the `ccc` terminfo capability.

Answer (score 3):

you might find this useful:

> ### 10.2. Changing Color Definitions
>
> The function `init_color()` can be used to change the rgb values for the colors defined by curses initially. Say you wanted to lighten the intensity of red color by a minuscule. Then you can use this function as
>
> ```
> init_color(COLOR_RED, 700, 0, 0);
> /* param 1     : color name
>  * param 2, 3, 4 : rgb content min = 0, max = 1000 */
> ```

source: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/color.html

Also, mario's hand (by his head) needs to be an extra pixel high, he hits the blocks with his hand not his head.

Comment: Note that you may be able to support more colors -- check the global var `COLORS` after calling `start_color()` and if it is greater than 8, you can use color numbers 8 and higher instead of changing the predefined colors.

Comment: Ok, but this way i will edit a color. What i want is create a color.
Like color_skin = (A rgb value).

Comment: [`init_color`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h3-init_color)  is only useful if the terminal can change colors (i.e., [`can_change_colors`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h3-can_change_color))